# How to get rid of black shadows in glass ring?

Tags: materials, lighting, shadows, glass, reflection

I'm making a glass ring in Blender and am running into a very persistent problem with very dark shadows inside the ring. I am working with the Cycles render engine, as in Eevee the glass just appears gray.
[You can view my file here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4592h4ez72s70z1/Glass%20Ring.blend?dl=0)

I have researched this on fora extensively and have already tried the following:

- Increase max bounces of Light Paths in render properties, this didn't help (also see screenshots for settings)
- Mix glass material with a transparant shader. This just makes the object 50% opaque it seems, which is not what I'm trying to achieve
- Play around with the brightness of the lights
- Reflective and retractive caustics are checked
- Add a mesh light source instead of area light, this didn't help either.

Does anybody have any other ideas? You would be of enormous help!

[image: Ring using mix shader with Glass BSDF and Transparent BSDF]

[image: Ring using Principled BSDF material]

image 1: Ring using mix shader with Glass BSDF and Transparent BSDF

image 2: Ring using Principled BSDF material

EDIT: Based on some first insights (THANK YOU!) I have now set a world texture, but still try to get rid of the excessive reflection of this world. I am looking to make the ring see-through like glass, though still distorting the background (blue circles on white in the back) as well.

Comment: Well, how did you mix the _Glass BSDF_ and _Transparent BSDF_? A screenshot of that setup would have been interesting instead of seeing the same material twice. If you simply used a mix factor of 0.5, than it's not just looking like it was set to 50% opacity, it is exactly what you have done...

Comment: Could you please highlight the dark shadows? If you're talking about the grey areas, it is just the world reflecting on your object, you need to plug a Texture > Environment Texture node into the Background of your World and upload an HDRI in order to have something else than your grey background

Comment: @moonboots That's what I suspect, too. Nevertheless there are things how you can improve the look of glass in Blender ;)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I added a screenshot that shows my settings for this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @moonboots I will try that! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann sure but it looks like a world problem here

Comment: @andreav The glass setup looks a bit like mine from a different question. However there is something missing in the _Maximum_ node. You have to either plug in the _Is Diffuse Ray_ or _Diffuse Length_ from the _Light Path_ node into the second input. This is to have darker, clearer shadows inside a glass and less light absorption. It doesn't matter if you use it with a _Glass BSDF_ or _Principled BSDF_ with transmission - but it doesn't work if you just a value in the second input. For your problem though this is not necessary, you can still use a single BSDF node without mixing.

Comment: @andreav Oh, and by the way, glass can sometimes have dark areas especially close to edges etc., the bounces for _Glossy_ can improve that a lot. A value of 8 which I see in your screenshot still isn't very much. You can increase this to 16 without increasing the render time very much but it looks a lot better. Just keep in mind that you have to increase the _Total_ bounces to 16 in this case as well.

Comment: @moonboots Definitely, I'm a bit ahead since I know people often struggle with more problems in glass materials as they keep trying to improve it :)

Answer (score 3):

Your object is just reflecting the world, which is grey for the moment, if you want to quickly test an HDRI, open the *Viewport Shading* panel, deactivate the *Scene World* option and choose an HDRI. If you want to render you'll need to plug an *Environment Texture* into the *Background* of your world material though.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I added a white studio environemtn texture. Now however it reflects a white studio; while I want the glass to be see-through and not reflect any environment at all – though I am looking for it to distort the blue and white background, so setting the IOR closer to 1 doesn't do the trick.

Comment: @andreav If you don't want the white studio to be reflected, you have to mix two _Background_ shaders together, the first one is the white studio, the second is simply black. As a mix factor take the _Light Path_ node and use the _Is Glossy Ray_ output.

Comment: @adreav glass reflects by definition, if you don't want to see any background and see the white and blue image instead, you should use it as an HDRI, or project it on planes all around your object (or on a sphere, which is the same as using an HDRI)

Comment: @moonboots Although I know what you mean, _projecting image on sphere_ ≠ _using an HDRI_  ;)

Comment: what do you mean? if you keep the UV sphere default unwrap and use an HDRI as material it will give the same result as a world HDRI, except you can zoom on the image, yes ok in that way it is not the same

Comment: @moonboots But an "image" is not necessary an HDRI, so it will have a lot of different qualities especially regarding lighting, and "using an HDRI" can be something different then "using an HDRI as Environment Texture in the world background". Beginners might confuse these things, I experienced people preview jpgs instead of HDRI for the world and wondering why it's dark, and others using HDRIs with an Image Texture set to "Sphere" instead of an Environment Texture set to "Equirectangular" and wondering about the result. I often realize I assume too much as evident for myself.

Comment: Thank you both a lot for your time and effort. I realize glass will reflect something but it just seems like it is a lot here... Mixing the world background with black didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann sure

Answer (score 0):

try checking the Transparent Glass box in the "Film" section.

[image: Transparent glass]

Comment: Sadly didn't work. :-(

Comment: Have you tried working with the IOR setting in the glass Node?